# Add up hh:mm written as a string together in php

Tags: php, function, time, strtotime

I am trying to get a total time from few times written as a strings in php.

Times as strings:
00.25, 07.35, 01.10, 00.00, 01.00, 00.22

With that I should get 10hrs12mins but I get 11hrs03mins.

```
function add() 
{
    $midnight = strtotime('0.00');

    $extra = strtotime(hours($extratime));
    $taxi = strtotime(hours($taxitime));
    $flt = strtotime($flttime);
    $res = strtotime(hours($options->restime));
    $hold = strtotime(hours($holdtime));

    $totalseconds = $extra + $taxi + $flt + $res + $hold;

    return date("H.i", $midnight + $totalseconds);
}
```

$holdtime, $taxitime, $extratime, $options->restime are all written as minutes and then converted to hours using:

```
function hours($min) 
{
    $mins = abs($min);
    $neg = ($min < 0) ? '-' : '' ;
    $hours = $mins / 60;
    $onlyhours = floor($hours);
    $onlymins = $mins - ($onlyhours*60);
    $time = sprintf("%s%d.%02d",$neg,$onlyhours,$onlymins);
    return $time;
}
```

The function hours works fine but function add doesn't as after displaying it I get 11.03 where it should be 10.12.

Thanks in advance,

Maciej.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not convert $holdtime, $taxitime, $extratime, $options->restime in hours.
Add these durations in minutes :

```
$total = $holdtime + $taxitime + $extratime + $options->restime;
```

Then convert $total in hours.